# Trouble printing to a specific Tray (PaperSource) using VB.NET PrinterSettings

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing

I've been having trouble automatically selecting a Tray (PaperSource) to print from on a specific printer (HP OfficeJet Pro 9020 series) using VB.NET. I have reduced my code to a bare minimum below to indicate the process I'm following.

After the print dialog has popped up and you select 'Tray 2' from the list. The line of code `prn.PrinterSettings = pd.PrinterSettings` applies that setting, and it subsequently prints from the correct tray. If, however, you just click ok on the dialog it prints from the wrong tray.

The strange thing is that, as you can see, I set the 'Tray 2' option in code, so, in theory that object should be exactly the same. I used `Newtonsoft.JSON` to serialise the `pd.PrinterSettings` object before and after I had selected 'Tray 2' in the dialog so I could compare the differences and they were both identical. The only differences at first were the ones I addressed in the code earlier on. They didn't make any difference though. Those being;

```
pd.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "IP_192.168.1.50"
pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Dispatch Office"
pd.PrinterSettings.Collate = False
```

But for whatever reason, it only works if I explicitly open the dialog and select the desired Tray and click ok. `prn.PrinterSettings = pd.PrinterSettings` is the only line of code that has any effect on what printer is used, so somewhere in `pd.PrinterSettings` there must be something missing that I couldn't see in the JSON string. I've had success with this code on other printers, but this specific printer seems to be different, but the problem has to be with VB.NET I would think.

Has anyone come across anything like this before? Here is my full code below.

```
Private Sub Print()
   Dim pd As New PrintDialog

   pd.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "IP_192.168.1.50"
   pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Dispatch Office"
   pd.PrinterSettings.Collate = False

   For Each paperSource As Printing.PaperSource In pd.PrinterSettings.PaperSources
      If paperSource.SourceName = "Tray 2" Then
         pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = paperSource
         Exit For
      End If
   Next

   If pd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
      Dim prn As New Printing.PrintDocument

      prn.PrinterSettings = pd.PrinterSettings

      AddHandler prn.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler
      prn.Print()
      RemoveHandler prn.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub PrintPageHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
   Dim myFont As New Font("Courier New", 9)
   Dim strTextFile = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\textfile.txt")
   args.Graphics.DrawString(strTextFile, New Font(myFont, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 50, 50)
End Sub
```

Also, just to confirm, this is independent of the print dialog.
The code below which is in the shortest form possible also does not work.

```
Private Sub PrintAuto()
   Dim ps As New Printing.PrinterSettings With {.PrinterName = "Dispatch Office"}
   ps.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = ps.PaperSources(3) ' Tray 2
   Dim prn As New Printing.PrintDocument With {.PrinterSettings = ps}

   AddHandler prn.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintPageHandler
   prn.Print()
   RemoveHandler prn.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintPageHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: You are changing `DefaultPageSettings` which is a baseline for the printer dialog to display something to the user, not the end result.

Comment: @GSerg That does seem odd, but it is the only option. There's no `PageSettings` option. Also, see Microsoft docs which suggests it is done this way. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.papersource?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Drawing_Printing_PageSettings_PaperSource

Comment: @GSerg I've added another block of code at the end of my original post just to be clear. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You mentioned comparing objects using json serialization; have you tried putting a breakpoint in the code and inspecting the objects in the watch window?  The watch window can see into actual type (not just static type) and private members, so you might be able to pick something up there that didn't serialize.

Comment: There's no `PaperSourceKind` of type `Tray 2` . If you need to provide a custom `PaperSource` and `PaperSize` to the PrintDocument, you need to build custom objects and specify the `Kind` and `RawKind` properties. Otherwise, pick one of the existing paper sources using the standard enumeration (you cannot make up a name, use the [PaperSourceKind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.papersourcekind) enumerator).

Comment: @Craig - Thanks, yes I stopped at a breakpoint and couldn't see any difference between the two objects. There was so much in there though that it was hard to compare which is why I decided to try JSON just in case I missed something.

Comment: @Jimi - Thanks for the info. I'll look at this when I'm back in tomorrow. I'm not sure if it'll work though as the "Tray 2" string is just a convenient way of selecting the object. I think the resultant kind was 257 or something from memory after doing that.

Comment: @Jimi - I tried doing it this way using Upper and Lower and a few others. It didn't work. I'll reiterate that when the `PrinterSettings` object comes back from the dialog, the selected `PaperSource` is set as follows, `.Kind = 257, .RawKind = 257, .SourceName = "Tray 2"` so those settings should work. They are the options that the printer driver provides. There are only four options, Automatically Select, Printer Auto Select, Main Tray or Tray 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afternoon All,

I do believe I have found a solution myself on this one. It is horrendously complicated and revolves around the Devmode structure within the `.PrinterSettings` object.

I owe this answer to Richard Dean who I stumbled across on Code Project.
Have a look at this link for all the details

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/488737/storing-and-recalling-printer-settings-in-csharp-n

I took the project and ported it over to VB.NET and then simplified it to the point that I could use it to achieve the results I'm after. The software that Richard wrote basically allows you to save this structure that the printer uses and recall it at a later date. I saved the .bin file with his application and now refer to said file in my code below.

The function `GetSettings` returns a `PrinterSettings` object linked to the specified printer and then overwrites the Devmode data that I saved earlier. This now prints to Tray 2 on my printer with only one click of a button.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Imports System.IO

Public Class GetPrinterSettings
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True)>
    Public Shared Function GlobalFree(ByVal handle As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True)>
    Public Shared Function GlobalLock(ByVal handle As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True)>
    Public Shared Function GlobalUnlock(ByVal handle As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Public Function GetSettings(PrinterName As String) As PrinterSettings

        Dim ps As PrinterSettings = New PrinterSettings()
        ps.PrinterName = PrinterName

        Dim Filename As String = "C:\Devmode.bin"

        If File.Exists(Filename) Then
            ' Gets the data from the arraylist and loads it back into memory

            ' int mode
            ' 1 = Load devmode structure from file
            ' 2 = Load devmode structure from arraylist
            Dim hDevMode As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero ' a handle to our current DEVMODE
            Dim pDevMode As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero ' a pointer to our current DEVMODE
            Dim TempArray As Byte()

            Try
                ' Obtain the current DEVMODE position in memory
                hDevMode = ps.GetHdevmode(ps.DefaultPageSettings)

                ' Obtain a lock on the handle and get an actual pointer so Windows won't move
                ' it around while we're messing with it
                pDevMode = GlobalLock(hDevMode)

                ' Overwrite our current DEVMODE in memory with the one we saved.
                ' They should be the same size since we haven't like upgraded the OS
                ' Or anything.

                ' Load devmode structure from file
                Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(Filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                TempArray = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}
                fs.Read(TempArray, 0, TempArray.Length)
                fs.Close()
                fs.Dispose()

                For i As Integer = 0 To TempArray.Length - 1
                    Marshal.WriteByte(pDevMode, i, TempArray(i))
                Next

                ' We're done messing
                GlobalUnlock(hDevMode)

                ' Tell our printer settings to use the one we just overwrote
                ps.SetHdevmode(hDevMode)
                ps.DefaultPageSettings.SetHdevmode(hDevMode)

                ' It's copied to our printer settings, so we can free the OS-level one
                GlobalFree(hDevMode)
            Catch ex As Exception
                If hDevMode <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                    GlobalUnlock(hDevMode)
                    GlobalFree(hDevMode) ' And to boot, we don't need that DEVMODE anymore, either
                    hDevMode = IntPtr.Zero
                End If
            End Try
        End If

        Return ps
    End Function

End Class
```

I hope this is useful to anyone in the same boat. Thanks again to Richard for publishing the source code. Please look at Richard's post for more details as it is a very useful and powerful tool.

Regards,

Henry